# My plugin can't include wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've got a very weird problem. I've got a plugin that works practically everywhere and on all the servers/wordpress installs I can test. However, I've got a user that can't use the plugin.

I'm using Thickbox with iframe to load my shortcode picker window in the editor, so I need to include wp-config.php. Here's the code I use to grab wp-config:

```
while(!is_file('wp-config.php')){
    if(is_dir('../')){ chdir('../'); }
    else die('Could not find WordPress.');
}
include('wp-config.php');
```

The thing is, it FINDS wp-config, but it can't include it. The page literally hangs at the include statement. No errors, nothing. I've added "echo" to each step in finding and including the file, but it just stops at the include directive.

The plugin works everywhere else, but not with the pop up iFrame and Thickbox. Any ideas? If I can't include wp-config, then I can't even set WP_DEBUG and see what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post this `wp-config` file here? Without DB details, of course... Oh, yes, are you sure you need `wp-config`? And not `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); require('wp-load.php');`?

Comment: I got it. I just gave up and included wp-load.php. Nope, I was on a client site and couldn't edit the wp-config since I didn't have FTP access. Still, it's weird that I can include config on all the other test sites but this one.

Answer (score 0):

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );